# Automated Heroku Database Backups to Amazon S3

Tags: cron, amazon-s3, heroku, rake-task

how to create rake task for

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
```

and call this task to the cron job

Answer (score 0):

try this https://github.com/joemsak/heroku_backup_task